# Adding local media to peer connection

Tags: android, webrtc

I am facing problem while adding the local media to peer connection. When i add the local media to peer connection I see the following error in logcat.

7-29 14:37:17.054: E/rtc(5482): # Fatal error in../../webrtc/modules/video_coding/main/source/video_sender.cc, line 81,

I open the video_sender.cc file and went through it. There is a comment at that line
"Register the send codec to be used."
Then i understood some problem with the codec.

How to register codec with local stream in android ?

```
void displayLocalMedia()
    {
        videoConstraints = CameraIntialization.intializeVideoConstraints();
        PeerConnectionFactory.initializeFieldTrials("WebRTC-SupportVP9/Enabled/");

        String cameraDeviceName = CameraIntialization.checkDeviceCamera();
        if(peerConnectionFactory==null)
        peerConnectionFactory = new PeerConnectionFactory();

        mediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
        VideoCapturer capturer = VideoCapturerAndroid.create(cameraDeviceName,null);

        videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(capturer,videoConstraints);
        videoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0",videoSource);
        videoTrack.setEnabled(true);

        try {
                /*renderer = VideoRendererGui.createGui(0, 0, 100, 100,ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT, true);
                videoTrack.addRenderer(renderer);
                System.out.println("VideoTrack.........." + videoTrack);

                remoteRenderer = VideoRendererGui.createGui(0, 0, 100, 100,ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL, true);    */  


                localRender = VideoRendererGui.create(
                    LOCAL_X_CONNECTED, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTED,
                    LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTED, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTED, ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT, false  );
                videoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localRender));

            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
        AudioTrack localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource);
        mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
        mediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);
        if(createPeerConnection()!=null)
            peerConnectionObj.addStream(mediaStream);

    }
```

Comment: Local media was getting added but not was reaching the other side. Resolved by creating peerConnection and adding MediaStream to peerConnection in same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. This is working perfectly for me...

```
private MediaStream localMS;
    private PeerConnectionFactory factory;



    public void setCamera() {
    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(listener, true, true,
                params.videoCodecHwAcceleration, mEGLcontext);
        factory = new PeerConnectionFactory();

        localMS = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
        if (pcParams.videoCallEnabled) {
            MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoHeight)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoWidth)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxFrameRate", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoFps)));
            videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("minFrameRate", Integer.toString(pcParams.videoFps)));

            videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(getVideoCapturer(), videoConstraints);
            localMS.addTrack(factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", videoSource));
        }

        AudioSource audioSource = factory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
        localMS.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0", audioSource));

        mListener.onLocalStream(localMS);
    }

    private VideoCapturer getVideoCapturer() {
        String frontCameraDeviceName = VideoCapturerAndroid.getNameOfFrontFacingDevice();
        return VideoCapturerAndroid.create(frontCameraDeviceName);
    }
```